# Logger warning using Elasticsearch Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm writing a Java console application to perform some document processing and adding documents to an Elasticsearch index.
I'm using a simple wrapper class to handle the communication with Elasticsearch.

The relevant excerpts from this wrapper class are the `getClientConnection()` method:

```
protected Client getClientConnection()
{
    if (this.client == null)
    {
        Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", this.clustername).build();

        this.client = new TransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddresses(new InetSocketTransportAddress(this.hostname, this.port));
    }

    return this.client;
}
```

and the `addToIndex()` method:

```
public void addToIndex(List<HashMap<String, Object>> documents, String index, String doctype)
{
    Client client = this.getClientConnection();
    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();

    IndexRequestBuilder requestBuilder = client.prepareIndex(index, doctype);

    for (HashMap<String, Object> curDocument : documents)
    {
        requestBuilder.setSource(curDocument);
        bulkRequest.add(requestBuilder);
    }

    BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();

    this.closeClientConnection();
}
```

Everything is working nice and dandy and the documents are being added to the index when I call this code from the console application, but when running it I'm getting some warning messages:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.elasticsearch.plugins).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I know that Elastic is using log4j for logging, but I'm not sure why and what it's trying to log.

As this is a standalone application I don't want to add the elasticsearch config directory to the class path. The application should be able to run on a machine not running Elastic.
It's also worth noting that in my application I'm using log4j2 for logging purposes.

Now my questions:

1. Is it possible to just disable the TransportClient's logger? I saw the LogConfigurator.configure method which takes a settings object argument, but I'm not sure how to use it.
2. Could I somehow inject my own logger into the TransportClient?

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem at the moment. Googling the problem description got me here. Did you solve the problem ? If so, could share the solution?

Comment: So I just opened an [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10421) regarding the this problem at the elasticsearch github repository. Hope the answer will come from there...

Answer (score 0):

There is no Null appender for log4j.  While you could do that with slf4j, I'm not sure if you can bridge a library that expects log4j to use slf4j instead.  Short of that (painful) exercise, I recommend you just add the log4j-1.2.jar to your classpath and configure a log4j.properties file with a root logger that points at stdout:

```
# Set root logger level to FATAL and its only appender to stdout.
log4j.rootLogger=FATAL, stdout

# stdout set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```

Now the only messages sent to the logger from ES will be fatal exceptions, which you probably want to know about, anyway.  Truly, you probably want ERROR level and you should code your own application to use log4j and log your own client calls.  In that case, you'll probably want a rolling file appender.  If you truly want to throw away all your log events, pipe your stdout and stderr to /dev/null:

```
$ ./myprog &> /dev/null
```

There are a bunch of variants that would work just as well, like using a file appender and limiting it's size to 1K or something.

And log4j is EOL.  So you could do the same thing but use the log4j2 jar and an appropriate json/xml configuration file for it.  I know it sounds painful but there are tons of examples and knowing the logging framework will be invaluable in your own code.